# NSDateFormatter same string for different dates

Tags: ios, macos, datepicker, nsdateformatter

Can someone explain  why NSDateFormatter return same strings from different dates:

```
    NSDateFormatter *f = [NSDateFormatter new];

f.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

NSDate *dateYear0 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateWithEra:0 year:0 month:3 day:31 hour:0 minute:0 second:0 nanosecond:0];
NSDate *dateYear1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateWithEra:0 year:1 month:3 day:31 hour:0 minute:0 second:0 nanosecond:0];

NSString *dateStrYear0 = [f stringFromDate:dateYear0];
NSString *dateStrYear1 = [f stringFromDate:dateYear1];

NSLog(@"dateYear0=%@ \t\t dateStrYear0=%@",dateYear0,dateStrYear0);
NSLog(@"dateYear1=%@ \t\t dateStrYear1=%@",dateYear1,dateStrYear1);
```

Both dateStr1 and dateStr2 have the same values:

**NSLog result:**

```
dateYear0=0001-03-30 21:57:56 +0000     dateStrYear0=03/31/0001
dateYear1=0000-03-30 21:57:56 +0000     dateStrYear1=03/31/0001
```

Its looks like 0 year affect this somehow?

Thanks

Comment: check DateHelper class which you implemented here, there must be some tricky changes

Comment: DateHelper work correctly. Code which use only NSDateFormatter produce same result.

Comment: when you are passing "[DateHelper dateWithYear:0 month:3 day:31]", please NSLog and check what does it returns. Don't execute "dateStr1"

Comment: The format you specify requires only one digit for the day, but you're passing two.

Comment: Edited code in question - only standard iOS/Mac API used.

Comment: How about testing with more realistic dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because year 0 doesn't exist in [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)). When dealing with AD dates minimum possible value for `NSDate` is "0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000" therefore it uses "0001" as year whenever a lower value used than 1. You can check minimum `NSDate` value with `distantPast` class method.

Also if you want to use BC dates you should check Apple's [guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html) for more information.